# Enabling user creation with " Active Directory Integration"

Tags: plugins

For our internal wordpress site, we have installed the plugin "[Active Directory Integration](http://wordpress.org/plugins/active-directory-integration/)" and we are able to have the users login using the domain password. 
How to have the users getting created automatically? Further I was not able to get a step-by-step guide that covers everything about this plug-in. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kannan.

Comment: Please link to the plugin so that others don't have to guess and look it up. Also it might make sense to inquire with plugin's developer about its specific functionality and integration.

Comment: @Rarst : Thanks for the comment. I have added the link. I am almost new to Wordpress and WP-Plugins. Trying on where to start.